# PHP JSON Decoding WoW raid progression

Tags: php, json

This code will echo the different subcategories but I want to get past this and get the data about current raids (number of boss kills for the different bosses).

Code:

```
$url = 'http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/kelthuzad/bigbranch?fields=statistics';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$char_json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($char_json['statistics']['subCategories'] as $p)
{
    echo $p[name].'<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
Character
Combat
Kills
Deaths
Quests
Dungeons & Raids
Skills
Travel
Social
Player vs. Player
Legacy
Pet Battles
Proving Grounds
```

I need to get where `name = 'Dungeons & Raids'` but I just can't do it. `$char_json['statistics']['subCategories']['Dungeons & Raids']` comes back  as `null`. The final data I am after is `quantity` as shown in this snippet of the API:

```
{"id":9317,"name":"Gruul kills (Normal Blackrock Foundry)","quantity":0,"lastUpdated":0,"money":false},
```

Comment: Please use the wiki/markdown syntax to make to question more beautiful and more readable

Comment: You should provide the full API output, e.g., provide what `print_r($char_json)` shows or something like that.

Comment: thank you for the edit, i didn't see where the edit link was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have done

`$char_json = json_decode($content, true);`

$char_json is an associative array. Do a `print_r($char_json);` to see the entire array structure.

Then it's a matter of either addressing the correct index, or possibly looping through the array if there are many elements.

If you still have questions post the output of print_r.

EDIT: I just looked at the data from your url. Dungeons & Raids is here:

`$char_json['statistics']['subCategories'][5]`

So you could do

```
foreach ($char_json['statistics']['subCategories'][5]['statistics'] as $stat) {
    $name = $stat['name'];
    $qty = $stat['quantity'];
    // etc...
}
```

This does assume Dungeons & Raids is always the 6th element of the larger array though. If that's not the case you would have to loop through each `$char_json['statistics']['subCategories']` until you found name = Dungeons & Raids.

Comment: $char_array['statistics']['subCategories'][5]

still contains the data i am looking for but when i add
['statistics'] again, its not there >.<

Comment: My mistake, when writing some quick test code against your data I changed your variable name from $char_json to $char_array. Just edited and changed it back to $char_json.